# Could you explain what "make pay" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I'm not clear about the phrase used here. Does "pay" in this context mean to score?

> GOAL - Mohamed Salah Fulham 2-2 Liverpool
>
> After being so organised for most of the game, the Fulham defence is a
> bit of a mess here and Liverpool **make them pa**y.

Answer (score 2):

To make someone pay means to punish them or get revenge.

As we can read from [Phrasemix](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/make-someone-pay):

You can use "for" to show why you want to get revenge on the person. For example, if someone insults you, you might think:

> I'll make you pay for saying that!

So, in regard to your sentence, I understand that Liverpool made Fulham pay for the previous goals the latter had scored.